# How to return in a cell all the matching values present in a column?

Tags: worksheet-function, csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Suppose I have the following data:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | idx1 | VAL1 |
| 2 | idx2 | VAL2 |
| 3 | idx3 | VAL3 |
| 4 | idx4 | VAL1 |
| 5 | idx5 | VAL4 |
| 6 | idx6 | VAL1 |
| 7 | idx7 | VAL1 |
| 8 | idx8 | VAL2 |
| 9 | idx9 | VAL5 |
| 10 | idx10 | VAL3 |

For each "VAL[n]" in column B, I would like to

1. get *all* the matching values present in column A;
2. concatenate them into a string;
3. put the concatenated text in a cell.

That is, in another sheet, I would like to get the following:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VAL1 | idx1, idx4, idx6, idx7 |
| 2 | VAL2 | idx2, idx8 |
| 3 | VAL3 | idx3, idx10 |
| 4 | VAL4 | idx5 |
| 5 | VAL5 | idx9 |

Is it possible to make that? If so, how can I make that?

Note: For step 1, which is the root of the issue, I tried to use the INDEX-MATCH function pair but this pair returns only the first matched value i.e. a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TEXTJOIN` function with the `IF` function. Adapt the following array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE(),IF($B$1:$B$10=D12,$A$1:$A$10,""))
```

With your cursor still in the formula bar, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for the curly braces to envelop the formula as seen on the image.

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks Reddy. It does work. Is there a way to sort alphabetically the matching values (note: in the sample data of my question, values in column A are sorted for simplicity)? That is, with reference to your example, in cell E12 I would like to ensure values are sorted automatically.

Comment: @Backo LibreOffice Calc does not have a SORT function like Excel that one can use on a formula. If you want to sort, you must select the range A1:B10, then click on Data -> Sort, set the criteria(s), click Ok, then use the formula I have given.